# How to disable automatic Nuget Package Update in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mono, nuget

How to disable automatic Nuget Package updates in Xamarin 5.9 (build 539) when opening a new Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the settings: Tools -> Options -> Nuget -> Package Updates

Answer (score 1):

For Mac this is found under: Visual Studio -> Preferences -> NuGet -> General

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!